# Deploy change set from sandbox to production unavailable

Tags: process-builder, deployment, change-set, api-version

I have a process builder which I want to build to production, when I create a change set it says that this change set requires the "45.0" or later platform version, if it was a visualforce page I could change the api version, but I couldn't do that for the process builder, how can I accomplish that?
The production runs in 44.0 api version and my sandbox in 45.0 api version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this article from salesforce [Version error when uploading Change Set](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181707&type=1)

You might just have to clone your change set and try deploying again.

Best Regards,
Amit

Comment: After I had deployed a change set from a v53 sandbox to a v53 sandbox, Salesforce would not let me upload it to v52 production, even though all components were Apex classes with v52 or lower. I cloned the change set and then it was possible to upload it to v52 production. So cloning solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have deployed by now, but for future readers, I would suggest cloning the Process Builder to get a new version.  I would expect the cloned version to have the latest API version.